# iOS: Push Notification and Re-Registering the device at Login.

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to register the device for Push Notification each time the User Logs In.

Right now in my AppDelete.m I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{

    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [[token componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    [self.pushClient registerDeviceToken:token withUser:loggedInUserName onSuccess:^{
        NSLog(@"successful registration");
    } onFailure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error userInfo]);
    }];
}
```

Q.  What do I need to do to call the above methods in my App Delegate each time the User Logs In?  i.e. The app is running.  A User logs out and logs back in with a different username, and now I need to register the device with that user name, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to persist APNS token, thats the way going forward for your situation.
As and when your app comes to foreground, you will get call in `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`. Now

1. remove old APNS token from NSUserDefaults if any (or whatever you like for persistence)
2. save APNS token into NSUserDefaults
3. and use saved token.

Answer (score 1):

You can always call the method registerForRemoteNotificationTypes after user is logged in.